# Custom Print button on Salesforce Page

Tags: apex

I just wanted to know if anyone has any idea or useful links about enabling print button (custom functionality) using apex?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@CRM Guy

you can use javascript functionality in your visualforce page just check my below code

```
  <apex:commandLink value="Print" onclick="window.print();"/>
```

Accept my Answer if it is useful means.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a useful link: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Visualforce_Extended_Print_Preview.  You might want to consider using [Field Sets](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm) to specify the fields that will appear on your print page.  They will allow you to add/remove fields without modifying code.

Comment: Thanks Peter.Surely will go thru it .What I was thinking that I will keep a button on VF, and underneath in APEX, can I trigger the functions from system that are triggered when a user enters Ctrl+P from keystroke?

Comment: You could look at creating print specific styles ([@media print](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)) for the current page you are on, so when they hit CTRL + P the browser uses those style sheets.  You could trap the CTRL + P command in JavaScript and do something, but that just captures CTRL + P.